# Slow-roasting top round beef

Tags: substitutions, beef, slow-cooking, roast-beef

I wanted to try out a recipe for a slow-roasted eye of round roast.  However, I was unable to find this cut at my local market, so I purchased a top round roast instead.  Can this cut be prepared the same way, or should I use a different technique?

The technique outlined in the recipe is as follows:

- Salt the exterior and let sit for 18–24 hours
- Season & oil the roast, and sear the exterior in a pan
- Roast at 225°F for about 2 hours
- Turn off oven and let roast sit undisturbed in the oven until it reaches an internal temperature of 140°F.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two cuts come from the same general area.  They eye of round is more lean, and generally tougher and less flavorful, given the lack of fat.  There is no reason you cannot use the cooking technique described on the top round.  Using a thermometer will ensure proper done-ness.  It will probably take a bit longer than the more narrow eye roast.

[image]

Comment: Do you mean 'there's no reason you cannot use the cooking technique?'

Comment: No worries @moscafj. I've never had much success with round roasts, they end up way too dry for my taste. Braised is better IMO, although if I'm braising it's hard to beat beef shin. Okay, now I'm hungry.